# Cannot Resolve PortableDeviceToHostImpl32 in jmtp library

Tags: javafx, usb, usb-drive, mtp, jmtp

I am using jmtp library and most of the code is working fine like device read , device file read and write. But when i used PortableDeviceToHostImpl32 for copy From Portable Device To Host show Cannot resolve "PortableDeviceToHostImpl32".

I have Download library from https://code.google.com/archive/p/jmtp/downloads. and successfully run the most of the things but stuck in copy From Portable Device to desktop and not known why this problem occurred.

OR what is the alternative of the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a very old abandoned project, nevertheless, going through project's known issue it seems implementation for `PortableDeviceToHostImpl32` was not done by the original developer and someone have provided "some sort" of solution so I would highly recommend to  read through the **[issue](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jmtp/issues/3)** and you might be able to use the code shared by commenter over there.

That being said it's never a good idea to use library that is not maintained, use alternatives such as:

[usb4java](http://usb4java.org/)

[lib-javax-usb3](https://github.com/KeyBridge/lib-javax-usb3)